# Which transformation gives more power, Super Saiyan Rage or Super Saiyan Blue Evolution?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Super there is a power scale for most of the super saiyans transformations, but some of them it's unclear where they fit. For example, this is the case of Super Saiyan Rage which is clear it's stronger than Super Saiyan 2 for example, and apparently stronger than Super Saiyan Blue considering how Trunks performed against Fused Zamasu versus how Goku and Vegeta in Super Saiyan Blue did, but from there on it doesnt seem to be data which states where it fits. Is there any info in any of all the Dragon Ball sources to know this?

Which transformation gives more power, Super Saiyan Rage or Super Saiyan Blue Evolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tough one, but as you can see in the Dragon Ball Super Card Game, Future Trunks in Super Sayan Rage mode has more power than Goku or Vegeta in Super Sayan Blue Evolution mode: http://www.dbs-cardgame.com/asia/cardlist/?search=true&category=428002&color=Blue

Also while fighting against Fused Zamasu, this state is shown to be able to power up even further, through the energy of humans across the Earth, gaining a massive boost in power. This power was able to destroy Fused Zamasu's body with ease.

Comment: The card I can see there it is Vegeta in regular super saiyan blue though, not evolution.

Comment: I'm assuming the evolved form of SSB is more powerful than normal SSB, so your question is still answered.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, every transformation has ups and downs. Rage mode though strong it is not as strong as Blue as per manga. In the manga, trunks doesn't even achieve that transformation as far as I remember. If we go by anime only, then Rage mode may seem like a bit stronger than blue but its not. As rage mode is a temporary form and cannot be attained at will. However, Evolution can be used at a whim of the user. Also in Evolution form, Vegeta almost held a candle against Jiren who is much more stronger than Zamasu. I would suggest you rather read this blog https://animehunch.com/2021/01/06/dragon-ball-super-what-is-super-saiyan-blue/ where he has explained well every super saiyan blue transformation